# Laravel Notifications - trying to pass data from controller

Tags: php, laravel, notifications

in `HomeController.php` I send notification like this `$user->notify(new OutdatedAELocation($conSite));`

then in `OutdatedAELocation.php` I am trying to use this data to store a notification to DB.

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class OutdatedAELocation extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($conSite)
    {
        $this->CSid = $conSite->id;
        $this->outdatedAes = $conSite->outdatedAes;
        $this->link = $conSite->link;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['database'];
    }


    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {   
        // dd($this);
        return [
            'conSite_id' => $this->CSid,
            'outdatedAes' => $this->outdatedAes,
            'link' => $this->link,
        ];
    }
}
```

for some reason, the data wont come to the `toArray` method.

when I call `dd($this)` at the end of __construct() method, its all there:

```
App\Notifications\OutdatedAELocation {#1329 ▼
  +id: null
  +locale: null
  +connection: null
  +queue: null
  +chainConnection: null
  +chainQueue: null
  +delay: null
  +middleware: []
  +chained: []
  +"CSid": 1
  +"outdatedAes": "info, "
  +"link": "https://app.com/query?location=1"
}
```

however, when i call `dd($this)` at first line of `toArray()` method, it's this:

```
App\Notifications\OutdatedAELocation {#1780 ▼
  +id: "ac659b25-7ff2-4500-adc8-72e6508d50c6"
  +locale: null
  +connection: null
  +queue: null
  +chainConnection: null
  +chainQueue: null
  +delay: null
  +middleware: []
  +chained: []
}
```

Please, how can I pass the data through?

Thank you.

Comment: I am not able to understand what's your problem is. Can you write more code pls?

Comment: in `__construct` i get data passed as $conSite, i want to store them in the model and call use them in `toArray()`, but i cannot access them there

Comment: where are the definitions of CSid, outdatedAes and link in the class?

Comment: ```$conSite = collect();
            $conSite->id = $mcs->id;
            $conSite->link = "www.website.com/" . $mcs->id;
$conSite->outdatedAes = "string"```

it's just integer, string, string

Comment: I am not talking about assigning value to them. The 3 fields are members of the class. You have to define them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you have to define the members in the class:

```
<?php

class OutdatedAELocation extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    // HERE you define the members
    var $CSid;
    var $outdatedAes;
    var $link;

    // ...
}
```

After that try `dd($conSite);` at the start of the constructor to see if you pass a full object to the class.